# Apache recently using increased CPU while idle

Tags: cpu-usage, apache2

I've been running an Ubuntu 14.04 server with the standard LAMP stack for quite some time now and have the system report hourly average CPU usage to me via daily emails. For a long time, this was reporting CPU idle time in the high 90s for the most part (it is a lightly loaded server).

Roughly a month or so ago, this changed and the server is now reporting idle time in the high 80s rather than high 90s. `top` reveals apache to be the consumer of most CPU:

```
top - 00:20:43 up 39 days, 22:34,  1 user,  load average: 0.34, 0.41, 0.39
Tasks: 165 total,   2 running, 163 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 10.0 us,  0.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 89.2 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   6110180 total,  5500892 used,   609288 free,   232448 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.  3502368 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
16235 www-data  20   0  503848  77680  41564 S   8.3  1.3   0:04.28 apache2
16124 www-data  20   0  506624  86688  47888 S   8.0  1.4   0:06.23 apache2
16351 www-data  20   0  506456  79224  41364 S   7.3  1.3   0:01.54 apache2
16301 www-data  20   0  506356  78908  41156 S   7.0  1.3   0:02.93 apache2
16102 www-data  20   0  507116  87292  48272 S   6.6  1.4   0:06.88 apache2
 1343 mysql     20   0 2670112 540216   8308 S   2.7  8.8 988:08.92 mysqld
16354 www-data  20   0  503248  76144  40636 S   1.3  1.2   0:01.29 apache2
16100 www-data  20   0  507016  80436  41524 S   1.0  1.3   0:07.12 apache2
```

I scratched my head for a while over this to determine what change I might have made to cause it. Web traffic has not increased during this timeframe (in fact, it has been lower than normal), and I can sit watching `apachetop` showing nothing much going on while the above `top` output continues.

I tried applying all latest patches this evening in the hope that perhaps some temporary glitch had been introduced in a recent update and had since been resolved, but to no avail.

It then occurred to me that it was perhaps around the same timeframe that I installed mod_security on the server. I've been running this in observe mode since then. I disabled that this evening and restarted apache, but the load appears unaffected by the change.

Can anybody suggest how I can diagnose what apache is busy doing? This is not currently a major concern, but I'd like to understand it before it does become one!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was some turkey in Chile polling xmlrpc.php several times a second on a WordPress site I wasn't monitoring with apachetop. Blocking the offending IP address solved the problem nicely!

In case anybody comes looking here again, I used mod_status to help me get to the bottom of this. Specifically, with mod_status installed and enabled, I enabled the /server-status path on one of my virtual hosts as follows (replacing `<my-current-ip>` with the current public facing IP address of my client PC):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName myhost.com
    ...
    <Location /server-status>
            SetHandler server-status
            Require ip <my-current-ip>
    </Location>
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

then visited `https://myhost.com/server-status` to get a full view of web traffic on the system. This fairly quickly revealed the bulk of traffic coming into the xmlrpc.php script on the virtual host in question.

From there, I tailed the access logs for that virtual host and could see the pattern of activity and the source IP address. It was then a matter of blocking the IP address using ufw as follows:

```
sudo ufw insert 1 deny from <the-bad-ip>
```

Note: using 'insert 1' in that command ensures it is applied ahead of any 'default allow' rules in the firewall configuration such as for ports 80 and 443, which otherwise render the filter about as useless as a chocolate teapot!

Comment: Unless you need xmlrpc enabled, I would disable it - there are a bunch of XMLRPC attack vectors for WordPress hence why I disable it heh

Comment: Been considering doing that also actually for said reasons

Comment: The other approach is to set up some type of IP restriction to only permit XMLRPC calls from *trusted* sources, though it may be easier to just shut it off if you don't use it.